# iOS8 Custom Keyboard Multiple layout options location

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Two questions but connected:

I would like to provide multiple layout for my custom keyboard similar to what you see for English(UK) > QWERTY, AZERTY and QWERTZ.

1. Which part of my iOS8 project should I change to be able to provide "disclosure indicator" when user adds the custom keyboard to the keyboards list like the English(UK) one?
2. How do I get a notification for a change in such user selection?

Did my best to search before asking. Thanks.